# From the GUI, how can I tell which version of Xubuntu I'm running?

Tags: xubuntu, versions

Doing this from the command line isn't hard, but I was shocked to find that I couldn't find a GUI way to do it. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Have it here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1981171.

Comment: @mikewhatever That's 8 years old. Does Xubuntu even have that menu any more?

Comment: No, probably not. I've just posted it to soften the shock, but you can check anyway. :~)

Comment: You could install `hardinfo` and that'll give you a GUI way to see which version you're running and a lot more. It's a pretty handy tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `xfce4-about`

**From Xubuntu 21.04 onward**

1. Press `ALT` `+` `F2`
2. Write `xfce4-about`
3. Press Enter

[image: new 4.16 xfce about]

Older versions of `xfce4-about` only report your xfce version and not the OS version.

Source: [XFCE 4.16 release tour](https://www.xfce.org/about/tour416)

## Using `zenity`

[image: Zenity showing Xubuntu release info]

1. Open a Terminal
2. `zenity --info --title "Xubuntu Release Info" --text "$(lsb_release -cir)"`
3. Press Enter

Comment: `xfce4-about` does not exist. It says it can be installed with another package, but I don't want to install something just to see the version of something that I already run. That is ridiculous.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus OP asked for a gui program. If you don't want a gui, use the terminal.

Comment: What makes you think I don't want a GUI. I do want a GUI. `xfce4-about` is a GUI program if I should believe this answer.